# Firefox 22+: MP3/MPEG 4/AAC Content-Type is not supported

Tags: firefox, mp3, h.264, mozilla, firefox-22

According to [this page](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/HTML/Supported_media_formats), Firefox 22+ on the Mac support MPEG 4, H.264, MP3 and AAC.

Still, I have been unable to play both MP3 audio files and H.264 video files using the audio and video tags in Firefox 22 and 23, getting the ol' "HTTP 'Content-Type' of 'xyz' is not supported" error.

I have tried the following content types to no avail:

- audio/mpeg
- audio/mp3
- audio/mpeg-3
- audio/x-mpeg-3
- video/mp4

Please note: There are similar questions here, but none of them have been asked since Firefox 22 was released on June 24.

Comment: Yup. Still not seuppoted on OSX on FF 24.. :(

Someone needs to go change that MDN page..

Answer (score 1):

Mac support for H.264 hasn't landed yet as of November 2013. The bug is [851290](https://bugzilla.mozilla.org/show_bug.cgi?id=851290).